# How do I check if a text variable in an array contains the most amount of text from every value of another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array,

`let array1 = ["one", "two", "three"]`

and I have a separate array,

`let array2 = [{var1: "one three two",  var2: "224824834"},{var1: "one two",  var2: "4348193564"}]`

*correct answer is var1*

I want to run through array2 and see if var1 contains all of whats in array1. The issue is that they're out of order, and some other things in array2 might match less of the values in array1, and I want the one that matches the MOST.

This is what I have now, but its bulky and isn't working up to speed. It glitches and I need it to be quick. Someone told me that you can do it much quicker but then proceeded to hide the code from me. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could help.

```
let possible_1 = [];
let possible_2 = [];
let product = {}
let nothing = false;

for (var i = 0; i < info.keywords.length; i++) {
         console.log('Checking every keyword..');
         if (i == 0) {
           console.log('First keyword... ' + info.keywords[i]);
           for (var v = 0; v < body.products.length; v++) {
             if (body.products[v].title.toLowerCase().indexOf(info.keywords[i].toLowerCase()) != -1) {
               console.log('Matched keyword... ' + info.keywords[i] + " " + body.products[v].title);
               possible_1.push(body.products[v])
             }
           }
           if (possible_1 == []) {
             nothing = true;
             console.log('Nothing found...');
           }
         } else {
           console.log('Not first keyword... ' + info.keywords[i]);
           if (possible_1 == []) {
             for (var b = 0; b < possible_2.length; b++) {
               if (possible_2[b].title.toLowerCase().indexOf(info.keywords[i].toLowerCase()) !=  -1) {
                 console.log('Matched keyword... ' + info.keywords[i] + " in " + possible_2[b].title);
                 possible_1.push(possible_2[b])
               }
             }
             if (info.keywords.length != i) {
               possible_2.length = 0;
             }
           } else {
             for (var s = 0; s < possible_1.length; s++) {
               if (possible_1[s].title.toLowerCase().indexOf(info.keywords[i].toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                 console.log('Matched keyword... ' + info.keywords[i] + " in " + possible_1[s].title);
                 possible_2.push(possible_1[s])
               }
             }
             if (info.keywords.length != i) {
               possible_2.length = 0;
             }
           }
         }
       }
       if (nothing != true) {
         if (possible_1 == []) {
           product = possible_2[0]
           console.log("Matched with product: " + possible_2[0].title);
         } else {
           product = possible_1[0]
           console.log("Matched with product: " + possible_1[0].title);
         }
       }
```

Comment: I don't know if you can use some external lib or not but `underscore.js` or `lodash` can make it easy for you. https://underscorejs.org/#difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce`, split the `var1` to create an array and then check if they are present in  `array1` using `includes` and maintain count.

```js
let array1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
let max = 0;
let count = 0;
let array2 = [{var1: "one three two",  var2: "224824834"},{var1: "one two",  var2: "4348193564"}];

const groupByOccurence = array2.reduce((accu, {var1}) => {
    count = 0;
    var1.split(" ").forEach((item) => {
        if(array1.includes(item)) {
            count++;
        }
    });
    if(max < count) max = count;
    accu.push({var1, count});
    return accu;
}, []);

const output = groupByOccurence.filter(({count}) => count === max);
console.log(output);
```